# UICollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

```
[myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
```

`myCollectionView` is not nil, and contains 3 items. I'm trying to scroll it programatically so that the 2nd item appears at the left edge of the collection view's frame.

The collection view does not move at all. I've also tried `setContentOffset`, which also has no affect. What would be preventing the collection view from scrolling?

EDIT: `setContentOffset` does actually work. I'd still be interested in knowing why `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` doesn't work though.

Comment: Right .. it JUST DOES NOT WORK ?!

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I had the same exact troubles and I was searching for related topics. If you still need it, I can tell you `setContentOffset` shouldn't be needed. The way I fixed it was to manually assign the `yourCollectionView.scrollEnabled` boolean property as `true`to allow it to scroll programmatically.